# Iterate through a list?

Tags: java, eclipse, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I have the following markup.

**Edit: Added full markup**

```
<div id="SelectList">
  <div class="select-area-left"></div>
  <div class="select-area-right"></div>
  <div id="SelectedOption">Option0</div>
  <ul id="ShowOptions">
    <li id="ShowOption0">Option0</li>
    <li id="ShowOption1">Option1</li>
    <li id="ShowOption2">Option2</li>
    <li id="ShowOption3">Option3</li>
    <li id="ShowOption4">Option4</li>
    <li id="ShowOption5">Option5</li>
    <li id="ShowOption6">Option6</li>
    <li id="ShowOption7">Option7</li>
    <li id="ShowOption8">Option8</li>
    <li id="ShowOption9">Option9</li>
    <li id="ShowOption10">Option10</li>
    <li id="ShowOption11">Option11</li>
    <li id="ShowOption12">Option12</li></ul></div>
```

And i'm trying to use the following code to print out each list elements text.

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='SelectList']/ul"));

            for (WebElement element: allElements) {
                  System.out.println(element.getText());
            }
```

But its just given a blank output. Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: your div id creteria does not matches with the actual

Comment: Forgot to edit that bit in my example. Fixed the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='SelectList']/ul/li"));

for (WebElement element: allElements) {
    System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

Basically you missed to point **li** element in the xpath used. Above code should work for you.

Comment: Its getting the right elements, but the text is blank.

Comment: Can you share the complete html. I created HTML out of that and applied my code. Gave me the correct output.